# String#include? only checking first position

Tags: ruby

I have a method that checks if a word includes a certain letter. The string#include? method's supposed to return true if the string object contains the letter in any position. However, my method is only returning true if there's a match between the letter (char_clicked) and the letter at the first position of the word (final_word). For example, if the final_word parameter is Spain, the method is only returning true if "S" is the char_clicked, it'll return false if char_clicked is any of "_pain"

Can you please ease my pain and tell me what I'm doing wrong...

```
def correct_guess?(char_clicked, final_word)
      puts char_clicked, final_word      #p, Spain  
      puts final_word.is_a?(String)      #true
      puts "checking if string"
      puts final_word.include?(char_clicked)  #false
  final_word.include?(char_clicked)
end
```

**Update**

I'm getting the same result even if I turn the string into an array and check for the letter

```
puts final_word.split("").include?(char_clicked)
```

However, if I use include in the console for that application, it works fine

```
>> s = "brazil"
=> "brazil"
>> s.include?("z")
=> true
```

---

Seeing as the first response to this question confirms that include? should be working the way I've shown it above, I'm providing more information which might hopefully explain why it's not working as one would expect

The final_word is being pulled out of the session before being sent to the correct_guess? method for checking. The char_clicked is pulled out of the parameters

```
def check 
    final_word = session[:word]
    char_clicked = params[:char_clicked]
    correct_guess = Game.correct_guess?(char_clicked, final_word)
    ....
```

Ajax request sending the char_clicked to the above check method

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/check",
        type: "POST",
        data: {char_clicked: this.get("char_clicked")},
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          var json = $.parseJSON(response);

          if (response.incorrect_guesses >= _this.get("threshold")) _this.set({lost: true});
          if (response.win) _this.set({win: true});

          _this.trigger("guessCheckedEvent", response);
        }
      })
    },
```

Comment: Can you also print `char_clicked` variabale?

Comment: Try `char_clicked.strip` (removing linebreaks and other accidental leading and trailing whitespace).

Comment: @steenslag it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @tdgs puts char_clicked  prints whatever letter's clicked but it returns false unless it's the first letter in the word

Comment: btw, the application is just an enki blog https://github.com/xaviershay/enki/blob/master/Gemfile that I'm adding to i.e. not a lot of source code, and I don't see any reason why gem author would override include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `include?` is overridden somewhere (monkeypatched). Does the following work?

```
def correct_guess?(char_clicked, final_word)
  final_word =~ /#{char_clicked}/i
end
```

It's unlikely that the regex-matcher method is overridden, too.

Comment: this is working in that it's telling me if the letter's included in the word. However, if I'm checking the include? method in the console for the same application and it's working fine there, then it shouldn't be overridden, should it, since the console uses the same application...If include were overridden in the application, then it would also be overridden in the rails console when I test it

Answer (score 1):

This was an upcase issue. The final_word was always a proper name, "Brazil," with only the first letter capitalized. However, the char_clicked was always uppercase.  The equality matching of `include?` method only returned true if there was a case match. If I changed the method to make final_word uppercase before checking if it included the char_clicked, it returned the expected true or false

```
final_word.upcase.include?(char_clicked)
```